# Not enough values while trying to insert data from table 1 to table 2

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to add one column in table but I get error that table needs to be empty.
I create backup table using following command

```
 CREATE TABLE attachments_backup
 AS
 SELECT * FROM attachments
```

When I create a backup table I insert data from  `attachments`  to  `attachments_backup`

```
 INSERT INTO attachments SELECT * FROM attachments_backup
```

Then I delete data from `table 1` (attachments)

```
 DELETE FROM attachments
```

I add column which I need to add in table attachment

```
 ALTER TABLE attachments 
 ADD ChildrenDirectory VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL
```

Right here problem occure. Since I add new column right now I can insert data from `table 2` `(attachment_backup)` to `table 1 (attachments)`

I try something like this

```
INSERT INTO attachments VALUES (AtaId,Belongs_To,ClientId,File_path,Id,Image_Path,Lock_,Name,Project_Id,Type,Category) SELECT * FROM attachments_backup
```

But this solution doesn't work since I get error message `"Not enought values"`

```
SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values
00947. 00000 -  "not enough values"
```

Does anyone now how to solve this kind of issue since I have no more idea ?

Attachments table

```
ATAID   NUMBER(10,0)
BELONGS_TO  NUMBER(10,0)
CLIENTID    NUMBER(10,0)
FILE_PATH   VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
ID  NUMBER(10,0)
IMAGE_PATH  VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
ISDELETED   NUMBER(10,0)
LOCK_   CHAR(1 CHAR)
NAME    VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
PROJECT_ID  NUMBER(10,0)
TYPE    VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)
CATEGORY    VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
CHILDRENDIRECTORY   VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
```

Attachments_backup

```
ATAID   NUMBER(10,0)
BELONGS_TO  NUMBER(10,0)
CLIENTID    NUMBER(10,0)
FILE_PATH   VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
ID  NUMBER(10,0)
IMAGE_PATH  VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
ISDELETED   NUMBER(10,0)
LOCK_   CHAR(1 CHAR)
NAME    VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
PROJECT_ID  NUMBER(10,0)
TYPE    VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)
CATEGORY    VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
```

Comment: You need to include definitions for all tables.

Comment: Done, I added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you're doing it **wrong**.

Except for *quick and dirty* selects, don't use asterisk `*`. Something like this:

```
insert into a select * from b
```

just waits for error to happen. **Always** name all columns involved. Yes, it requires some more typing, but is safe. So:

```
insert into a (empno, ename, job, sal)
select empno, ename, job, sal 
from b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome,

1. You can add new column to an existing table using an alter command, even if the table is not empty
2. To insert from table "A" to table "B" or vice-versa, you need to have exact number of columns to perform "select * " type insert

Comment: WoWw thank you :) It works your first solution :) 
One possible error here is that I didn't use  ALTER TABLE and that's why I get error :)